# need help in choosing the right tool

Tags: software-design

I have a client who has set-up a testing environment in some AI language. It basically runs some predefined test cases  and stores the results in as log files (comma separated txt files). My job is to identify and suggest a reporting system and I have these options in mind. either
1. Importing the logs into MSSQL and use the reporting(SSRS) it uses
2. or us import the logs to MySQL and use PHP to develop custom reporting.

I am thinking that going with option2 is better. The reason for this is, the logs are inconsistent and contain unexpected wild characters that normally DB's don't accept. So, I can write some scripts in php before loading them to the database.

Can anyone please suggest if this is your problem what will you suggest to do?

Answer (score 2):

It depends how fancy you need to be. If the data is in CSV files, you could even go so simple as to load it into Excel (or their favorite spreadsheet tool), and use spreadsheet macros to analyze it.

Comment: Its is a bit complicated than normal csv file. So using excel is out of option.